# esptool.FatalError: Timed out waiting for packet header Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266, esptool

I have a ESP8266. The last working state was loading just fine and wasn't getting any errors on esptool. However, after coming back to the code and running the Arduino. To give some background, I am creating a nixie clock with ESP8266.

```
esptool.FatalError: Timed out waiting for packet header
```

It's currently on baud: 57600
I will add the full error below:

```
    esptool.py v2.6
2.6
esptool.py v2.6
Serial port /dev/cu.wchusbserial14130
Connecting........_
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
MAC: dc:4f:22:11:68:e3
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Configuring flash size...
Auto-detected Flash size: 4MB
Compressed 347296 bytes to 246702...

Writing at 0x00000000... (6 %)
Writing at 0x00004000... (12 %)
Writing at 0x00008000... (18 %)
Writing at 0x0000c000... (25 %)
Writing at 0x00010000... (31 %)
Writing at 0x00014000... (37 %)
Writing at 0x00018000... (43 %)
Writing at 0x0001c000... (50 %)
Writing at 0x00020000... (56 %)
Writing at 0x00024000... (62 %)
Writing at 0x00028000... (68 %)
Writing at 0x0002c000... (75 %)
Writing at 0x00030000... (81 %)
Writing at 0x00034000... (87 %)
Writing at 0x00038000... (93 %)Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Dos/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/upload.py", line 25, in <module>
    esptool.main(fakeargs)
  File "/Users/Dos/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 2698, in main
    operation_func(esp, args)
  File "/Users/Dos/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 2158, in write_flash
    esp.flash_defl_block(block, seq, timeout=DEFAULT_TIMEOUT * ratio * 2)
  File "/Users/Dos/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 104, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Dos/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 632, in flash_defl_block
    self.ESP_FLASH_DEFL_DATA, struct.pack('<IIII', len(data), seq, 0, 0) + data, self.checksum(data), timeout=timeout)
  File "/Users/Dos/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 354, in check_command
    val, data = self.command(op, data, chk, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Users/Dos/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 332, in command
    p = self.read()
  File "/Users/Dos/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 277, in read
    return next(self._slip_reader)
  File "/Users/Dos/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 1877, in slip_reader
    raise FatalError("Timed out waiting for packet %s" % waiting_for)
esptool.FatalError: Timed out waiting for packet header
esptool.FatalError: Timed out waiting for packet header
```

Hopefully someone can help out or give me some knowledge as to why this has occurred. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/arduino/info